# Why Hat Brim Up?

Tags: minhag, clothing, hats

Rav Chaim Kanievsky zt"l would [often](https://mishpacha.com/a-whole-world-inside/) [tell](https://yated.com/rav-chaim-ztl/) [people](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/18/obituaries/rabbi-chaim-kanievsky-dea.html) to wear the brim of their hat up. Why was he makpid, and was this written in any of his seforim?

Comment: Maybe Rav Kanievsky felt wearing your brim turned down was chukas hagoy, or possibly yuhara?

Comment: Maybe to keep your head down and in the sefarim? Simple balance if your head is down in a book and your hat is on.

Answer (score 2):

From the NY Times [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/18/obituaries/rabbi-chaim-kanievsky-dea.html&ved=2ahUKEwiWxIfp3ZuDAxWAMlkFHfTaCO4QFnoECB0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3HydIHjVUSl3iVpYnoYQwB) (titled "Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky, Venerated Talmudic Scholar, Dies at 94"):

> Rabbi Kanievsky told him that he would recover if he wore his hat brim up, in the old-fashioned style of European Jews. He did, he said, and the tumor turned out to be benign.

He was apparently makpid on keeping the tradition.

I just found on the website [bechadrei hareidim](https://www.bhol.co.il/news/761175) that Rav chaim was heard saying once that the Chazon Ish did not approve of the snap being bent down.

> מיד אחר כך סר העיתונאי לביתו של שר התורה הגר"ח קנייבסקי. להפתעתו, תוך כדי שהוא מעתיר עליו ברכות, הושיט הגר"ח את ידו והרים את שולי הכובע "הקנייטש" כלפי מעלה. הרב קנייבסקי עשה כן והסביר את עצמו באידיש.
> לשאלתו של גיל, הסביר מקורבו של הרב כי ר' חיים אמר ש"החזון איש לא אהב שהולכים עם הקנייטש למטה".

Comment: This doesn't really explain why he was makpid, except to say 'because the Chazon ish was', which doesn't really address the OPs question

Comment: I challenge the OP's statement of him being makpid. There are numerous accounts of people visiting him, where he didn't mention anything about the hat being bent down. I therefore answered as to why, when he felt the need to say something, did he say to 'keep the brim up.'

Comment: But why _did_ he say to keep the brim up, when he did? Because the Chazon ish said to? Again, that doesn't really address the OP's actual question

Comment: Or do you mean to say he said to do it because keeping the brim up heals?